# Taylor expansion of $\exp(\sin x)$ around $c=0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Consider the Taylor's expansion around $c=0$
>   and find the first 4 terms for the function $\exp(\sin x)$.

I have done this but I'm not sure if is correct.

$$e^{\sin x}=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This is hard to read.  You are asked for the first four terms but instead you appear to write out  three terms and then veer off into something else.  What do those three dots represent?  What is $n$ in that expression?  For the first few terms you can always check your work in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+exp%28sin%28x%29%29)

Comment: @lulu Perhaps the OP is trying to take the Taylor series of e^t at t=0 and substitute the Taylor series of t=sin(x) at x=0 to get the desired result?

Comment: What you have written is an approximation to $(e^x)^{\sin x}=e^{x\sin x}$. Something pretty different.

Answer (score 2):

We may avoid the use of the definition, by taking the **composition** of the expansions of $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$:
$$\begin{align}
e^{\sin(x)}&=e^{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)}\\
&=1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)\right)
+\frac{1}{2!}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^4)\right)^2
\\&\qquad+\frac{1}{3!}\left(x+o(x^2)\right)^3+\frac{1}{4!}\left(x+o(x^2)\right)^4+o(x^4)\\
&=1+x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{6}+\frac{x^3}{6}
+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\\
&=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f(x)= e^{\sin x}$, compute $f', f''$ and $f'''$. Then the first 4 terms are

$f(0), f'(0)x, \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2$ and $\frac{f'''(0)}{6}x^3.$

Answer (score 0):

You know that$$e^y=1+y+\frac12y^2+\frac16y^3+\frac1{24}y^4+\cdots\tag1$$and that$$\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\tag2$$So, in the RHS of$(1)$ replace $y$ with the RHS of $(2)$ and then forget the monomials whose degree is greater than $4$.

Comment: But after that **why** we can **collect** power of $x^n$.?

Comment: @MeetPatel I have no idea about what that question means.

Comment: My question is why we can rearrange here

Comment: Please check question number 4841508. where I ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

You want terms up to $x^3$. The exponential is $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}2+\cdots$ and the sine $\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$. Hence you only need to expand from two terms of the sine, as the others already exceed the degree $3$.

Now, only expanding the necessary terms

$$\begin{align}1&\to1\\
t&\to x-\frac{x^3}6\\
\frac{t^2}2&\to\frac{x^2}2-\cdots\\
\frac{t^3}6&\to\frac{x^3}6-\cdots
\end{align}$$

and in total

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}2+0\,x^3.$$

---

With a little more courage, up to degree $5$:

$$\begin{align}1&\to1\\
t&\to x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}\\
\frac{t^2}2&\to\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}6\cdots\\
\frac{t^3}{6}&\to\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{12}\cdots\\
\frac{t^4}{24}&\to\frac{x^4}{24}\cdots\\
\frac{t^5}{120}&\to\frac{x^5}{120}\cdots
\end{align}$$

gives

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}8-\frac{x^5}{15}.$$